# Drag and Drop with datalist items:

Tags: asp.net, drag-and-drop, datalist

Can I use WebPartsZone inside a datalist control?

I need to have draggable items inside a datalist control and datalist items
must be able to dragged and dropped into a control like datalist, Div tag,
etc., and to find the count of the items in the drop zone. I also need the
items which are dragged and dropped to be saved in a database table.

So is it a good idea to use WebParts?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will helps you...

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/dragdrop/dd-reorder.html

http://dotnetslackers.com/projects/AjaxDataControls/DataList/DragNDrop.aspx